# How to use the Azure docker API

Tags: ruby, azure, docker, dockerfile

I have a problem when I upload my API on the Azure service app, a ping on port 80 does not find it and returns an error.

If I manually launch my docker on the machine via SSH with `--network=host`, and I ping on port 80 it works.

It may be a bad configuration on my part on the Dockerfile, but I don't know what it is.

How can I fix this problem?

```
FROM ruby:2.4

RUN curl -sL https://deb.nodesource.com/setup_12.x | bash -
RUN curl -sS https://dl.yarnpkg.com/debian/pubkey.gpg | apt-key add -
RUN echo "deb https://dl.yarnpkg.com/debian/ stable main" | tee /etc/apt/sources.list.d/yarn.list && \
apt-get update && apt-get install -qq -y build-essential libpq-dev nodejs yarn

WORKDIR /api

COPY . .

RUN bundle install

CMD bundle exec thin -p 80 start

EXPOSE 80
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the Azure app service portal, under the `settings -> configuration -> Application Settings` , please check if you have added a property `PORT`.

If not, add `80`.

[image: port config in app service]

Comment: Hi , thanks for the help but I had already added the variable PORT in the configuration.

and the result is still the same i got a "  didn't respond to HTTP pings on port: 80 "

Comment: I figured it out , where the problem come from , thanks for your time .

Comment: If you figured it out, then create an answer detailing the fix. That helps others in the future solve the same problem. As the question sits currently, nobody has any idea what helped, making the question pretty useless.